# Take non-nested JSON String and Build Json Nested String

Tags: java, json, rest, api, cassandra

This is very new to me. I am reading data from a cassandra table. This data is being extracted via a "select json * ..." query but here's the thing. The format of that json is

```
{"acct_ref_nb": 1401040701, "txn_pst_dt": "2020-02-26", "txn_pst_tm": 1934131, "txn_am": 15000.0 ....
```

Every field is in quotation marks, followed by a colon, followed by the value, then a comma and the next field, so on and so forth.

We need to reformat this and have a nested structure. We also need to change the names of the fields. So you would have something like...

```
"{
  "ccEvent": {
    "account": {
      "accountReferenceNumber": 1401040701,
      "transactionPostDate": "2020-02-26",
      "transactionPostTime": 1934131,
      "transactionAmount": 15000.0,
........
```

Is there a preferred library to do this? I'm literally lost even at a high level on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Cassandra support nested JSON, so that should give you some advantage on querying the data in the way you want it...to some extent. After that, it's just a matter of mapping the fields. A completely different business would be **if you don't have control on the query**; at that point I guess you would need to fetch, map, and remap :big_time:

Comment: I absolutely have control of the query. It's in the same code. Right now I'm doing a simple "select json * from <table_name". Does the table have to be created nested or I can define that in my query?

Comment: to get nested JSON objects, they need to be declared as UDTs (user defined types)